# Impact on existing Android application when upgrading Drive v2 to v3 (Using Google Sign-In)

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-console, google-cloud-console

We have recently upgraded our Android application from Drive v2 to use Drive v3 API. The last time we upgraded was when Google Drive had its own individual web console. During the upgrade we noticed that we now have to use GoogleSignIn to access Drive. We no longer need an individual API key like in Drive v2. Instead of a key, we need to generate a "google-services.json" file and include that in our application. Throughout the entire upgrade process we have been using a test account and have yet to perform these changes on the production account.

What will happen to the existing production Android application when we generate the new JSON file and start using Drive v3 through GoogleSignIn, will v2 still be supported in the existing versions of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are things that needs to be cleared up. The notable changes to v3 according to [v3 Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#v2) are:

> The differences between Drive API v3 and v2 are mainly changes to
>   field names and removal of duplicate functionality.
>
> **Notable changes**
>
> - Full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left
>     unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.
> - Duplicate and obsolete functionality has been removed. Examples:
>
>   - The Children and Parents collections have been removed. Use files.list instead.
>   - The Realtime.* methods have been removed. See the Realtime API documentation for alternatives.
> - A number of field and parameter names have changed and affects accessing fields in resources as well as q and fields expressions.
>     Examples include:
>
>   - The property name is now used in placed of title.
>   - All date/time fields are now suffixed with Time instead of Date.
>   - Results from list operations no longer use a generic items field to contain the result set. Results are now included in a field named
>       for the corresponding resource type (e.g. files, changes, etc.).
> - All update operations now use PATCH instead of PUT
> - The exportLinks field has been removed from files. To export Google Documents, use the files.export method instead.
> - The general approach for changes.list has changed. Opaque page tokens are now used in place of change ids. To poll the change
>     collection, first call changes.getStartPageToken for the initial
>     value. For subsequent queries, uses the newStartPageToken value
>     returned from changes.list.\

Notice that Google Sign was not mentioned contrary to what you've stated. I think it's just one of the alternative/easier ways to log-in. You can still use v2.

Check the [v3 Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) for code reference if you ever want to use v3.

Comment: I think the issue is that Java SDK changed at the same time as the v2->v3 migration. So you're right that the Drive API doesn't directly affect auth, but the changes to the Java SDK do.